# Prevent users from installing metro applications, but still let them install classical applications?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can disable the Windows store on Windows 8 completely](https://superuser.com/questions/495924/how-can-disable-the-windows-store-on-windows-8-completely)

Is there a way to prevent users from install the fancy new Metro/Modern UI app store applications, but still give them the ability to install classic desktop applications?

Comment: People seem to be distracted by metro, we give them the ability to install applications due to some vague problems with legacy control software.

Comment: Seems to be pretty much what's been discussed in [How can disable the Windows store on Windows 8 completely](http://superuser.com/questions/495924/how-can-disable-the-windows-store-on-windows-8-completely) already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Metro applications are installed via the Windows Store you can disable it, that doesn't affect users ability to install regular applications.

If you are using the Pro or Enterprise version of Windows 8, you can use the policies editor to do so; this is how to do it:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to search for it or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Run" dialog, either way type `gpedit.msc`.
2. Open it and navigate to `User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Store`.
3. Enable `Turn off the Store application`, and apply the changes.
4. Enforce the new policy by entering `gpupdate /force` in the "Run" dialog or log off and back on again.

[image: Said policy]

If you are using the Core version of Windows 8 you won't have the policies editor, so the change will have to be done in the registry itself; this is how:

1. Search for `regedit` in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or enter that in <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore`. Note that it is normal if that key doesn't exist, create it if that's the case.
3. Add or modify a `DWORD` value named `RemoveWindowsStore`.
4. Set it to `1` to disable its access. To enable it back again set it to `0` or delete the value. In this procedure the enforcement takes place right away (haven't tried with the store already opened though).

[image: Registry key and value]

Also, note that this change is per user and not system wide so it doesn't prevent other users from accessing the Windows Store and install Metro applications.